# Hide anchor tag with name

Tags: jquery

i would like to hide every anchor link on my page thats starts/contains with "Mobile"

```
<a href="#">Mobile</a>
```

How can i achieve this with jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selecto), which select all elements that contain the specified text. But it will not ensure that text starts with `"Mobile"`

```
$('a:contains(Mobile)').hide();
```

If you want to check multiple condition then you can use filter. If you find Mobile it first index of text then you do not need the contains.

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().indexOf("Mobile") == 0;
}).hide();
```

Comment: I think OP also stated that it should start with 'Mobile'.

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
$("a").filter(function(idx) {
   return this.innerHTML.indexOf('Mobile') == 0;
}).hide();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if the "mobile" text is more than once?

Answer (score 0):

For start and contains "Mobile". Use this:

```
$('a').filter(function(){ 
    return /^Mobile/ig.test(this.innerHTML); 
}).hide();
```

For only contain "Mobile" anywhere in the text. Use this:

```
$('a').filter(function(){ 
    return /Mobile/ig.test(this.innerHTML); 
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.each()` in jquery

```
$("a").each(function(idx,val) {
   return $(this).text().indexOf('Mobile') > -1;
}).hide();
```